# Shunt resistor with ADS1115

Tags: shunt

I am trying to develop an off grid solar monitoring system. In order to measure solar input current I am using a 50 A/75 mV shunt with an Adafruit ADS1115 (V<sub>DD</sub>=5 V).

However, when I connected A0, A1 of the ADS1115, I fried the IC. I have already fried two ADS1115 ICs.

I have attached my connection diagram for your reference.

[image: Connection diagram]

Comment: -1 for not rotating the picture correctly.

Comment: Another -1 from me because of the lack of care in posting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your grounds.

Overall, the simplest way is to use a Hall effect sensor to measure DC current, although it's less precise. As on solar installation you can have high voltage and big current, its fairly dangerous to do intrusive measurement.

Also you don't know what the charge controller is doing, and you may have offset in voltage in either the + or -.

A dirty way to do it is to power the board through an isolated power supply, and connect the negative pin of the shunt to the board GND. But you have to keep in mind that with this setup, your board might be at the panel voltage, so ONLY do it if the panel voltage is below 50V which is the safety limit.

Beyond 50V, you would need proper design and safety, thus the easiest is the DC Hall sensor or a high side shunt translator / optical isolation.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar setup because shunt resistors are typically more accurate than hall effect sensors.  I don't measure the current from the panels, themselves because my charge controller (Morningstar TriStar MPPT-60) already does a pretty good job of that.  Furthermore, my small panel array regularly outputs around 75 volts (and I might add to it, pushing it to just under 150 volts).  What I really need to know is the system voltage/current after the charge controller - the battery bank and the load (primarily through an inverter).  It's currently set up as a 24 volt system, but I hope to reconfigure the battery bank and upgrade to a 48 volt inverter, next year.

- My first shunt measures current from the charge controller.
- My second shunt measures current to the inverter (primary load).
- My third shunt measures current into and out of the battery bank (so, two    separate measurements on that particular shunt).

I followed the example depicted below, but instead of Bayite meters, I used an Arduino Nano and two ADS1115s (in differential mode).  Also take notice that the example I followed, has the shunts installed on the **negative** rails.

[image: This is an example that worked well for me]

Comment: You should complete your answer by stating *why* you do not measure the solar panel directly. I understand why, but many newbies here do not. Complete answers have a better chance of upvotes.

Comment: I didn't measure from the panels, directly because I don't see a need for that.  If I saw it as helpful to what I'm doing, I might have looked into that, but I don't understand why anyone would do that.  I've never seen a solar panel system where anyone has installed a shunt resistor to measure the panels, directly.  I'm not certain, but I imagine all solar charge controllers already do that.  Maybe there's some reason to measure from there that's unknown to me?

Comment: +1 - Thanks for the update :-)